# Converting to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do the most simplest thing this morning but my brain will not engage.. I have been learning basic javascript and Jquery over the last few weeks. I have a snippet of javascript code that I would like to convert to jquery, I would like my javascript to be unobtrusive.

The snippet of code is

```
<p>
    This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a>
</p>
<div id="light" class="white_content">
    This is the lightbox content. 
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Im working on making this lightbox a little more efficient but cannot seem to work out how to convert today.. Any help appreciated

Comment: nothing, i dont know where to start, just some pointers in the right direction would help

Comment: Use a span for the block of text "here", then assign a class or id (I think id might be appropriate). Use jQuery to assign click event handler to it. Probably can do the same for the "Close" text.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who has answered, great help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to:

```
<p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click
   <a href="#" id="a_show">here</a></p>

<div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content.
<a href="#" id="a_close">Close</a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Then the jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#a_show").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent's the click from firing - like JavaScript:void(0)
      $("#light").css("display","block");
      $("#fade").css("display","block");
  });

  $("#a_close").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent's the click from firing - like JavaScript:void(0)
      $("#light").css("display","none");
      $("#fade").css("display","none");
  });
});
```

Or you can use the `fadeIn` / `fadeOut` jQuery methods, for a nicer visual effect - if you want the instant effect then use `show()` / `hide()` in it's place:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#a_show").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent's the click from firing - like JavaScript:void(0)
      $("#light").fadeIn();
      $("#fade").fadeIn();
  });

  $("#a_close").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Prevent's the click from firing - like JavaScript:void(0)
      $("#light").fadeOut();
      $("#fade").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

The first example is like for like, and can be useful for changing other CSS properties via jQuery - However if you want to show / hide or fade elements then use the native jQuery methods as in the second example.

Comment: No problem - If you know some JavaScript and CSS then you're in pretty good shape for jQuery. The Selectors are the real trick - `$("element.class#id")`. So, are you can see above, I hope, is that we're binding the click to the element id, `#a_show` or `#a_close`, then we can do jQuery or just any JavaScript within! It's the same to bind other jQuery methods, we could do the same with `mouseenter` for example, the syntax is the same: `$("#a_show").mouseenter(function() { ...stuff... });`

Comment: any recommendations for  resources? the simpler its explained the better :)

Comment: I learn most of my jQuery from the jQuery site - Make sure your understanding of CSS is solid, as without it, you'll keep hitting problems with jQuery (wrong elements selected etc...) - W3Schools always used to be good: http://w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp worth a look to start with!

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour from `javascript:void(0);` can be reproduced by `return false` when placed inside a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) binding.

`document.getElementById('light')` can be re-written as `$("#light")`.

You will need to add classes or IDs to your links in order to target them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function() { // replace this selector as appropriate
        // do stuff here - lookup css in the JQuery docs
        return false; // prevents the link's default action - see also e.preventDefault() in the docs
    });
});
```

Comment: Or just the `e.preventDefault()` method of jQuery - You'll need to pass `e` (or whatever name you wish) into the `click` like: `$("cheese").click(function(e) { ...stuff...; e.preventDefault() }` - If you're going to use jQuery, you may as well use the whole lot!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of javascript `style.display='none','block'` jquery user `Hide() ,show()` methods

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function() { 

$("#fade").hide();
$("#light").show();

        return false;
    });
});
```

but to understand all this you should start learning [Jquery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) first,

Answer (score 1):

lets say you have a id="show" on the first a tag and a id="hide" on the 2.

```
$("#show").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#light, #fade").show()
})
$("#hide").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
   $("#light, #fade").hide()
})
```

now this is not inline scripting like youre example so you need to place it in a  tag or external script file you then pull in whith a  tag

when learning jquery i can recoment the [Jquery for designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/) videos

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. Seems like a few beat me to it.

Here's my answer for what it's worth:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#a1").click(function() {
            $('#light').show();
            $('#fade').show();
        });
        $("#close").click(function() {
            $('#light').hide();
            $('#fade').hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a id="a1" href="#">here</a></p>
    <div id="light" class="white_content" style="display:none">This is the lightbox content. 
    <a id="close" href = "#">Close</a>
    </div>
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you are trying to create a lightbox, why re-invent the wheel? If you google around you'll find some prebuild jQuery plugins...

http://line25.com/articles/rounding-up-the-top-10-jquery-lightbox-scripts